# How to read metadata from Sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

Sometimes I use SQLite database but it's quite common that I don't know anything about its structure.

I need to retrieve all metadata like the name of a database or table, the data type of a column, primary keys, foreign keys, or access privileges.

MSSQL has information_schema for this purpose but is there something similar for SQLite?

Comment: Check [SQLite Pragmas](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info), and `SELECT *  FROM sqlite_master ;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equivalent of, for instance, MySQL `describe t1;` is

```
PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(t1);
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE tbl_name = 't1';
```

is also useful. Most of the time, however, I simply use

```
.schema t1
```

which outputs the SQL definition of the table or view, even with the original comments (exactly the same as `SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE...`, with less typing. `.sch` works too.)